# Difference between Intern's / Leadfoot's timeout functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-testing, intern, leadfoot

Leadfoot has the method [setTimeout()](https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/Command.html#setTimeout) which takes 'script', 'implicit', or 'page load' as parameters, but it also has [setPageLoadTimeout()](https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/Command.html#setPageLoadTimeout), and [setFindTimeout()](https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/Command.html#setFindTimeout).  What is the difference between setFindTimeout and implicit?  What is the difference between setPageLoadTimeout and page load?  Is using both overkill?  Is one of the better than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specialized methods `setPageLoadTimeout`, `setFindTimeout`, and `setExecuteAsyncTimeout` all call `setTimeout` (see https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/Session.js.html#line2198). You can use either the specialized methods or the generic `setTimeout`, but it's typical to use the specialized methods.

The specialized convenience functions were created because they’re way clearer about what they actually do: `setFindTimeout` sets the timeout for `find` calls, and `setExecuteAsyncTimeout` sets the timeout for `executeAsync` calls.